# Angular2 Get element where an event is fired from

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here is my code :

```
<div id="foo" (click)="$event.target.classList.toggle('selected')">
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```

I would like to toggle the class 'selected' on the `div#foo` thus `$event.target` isn't correct since clicking one of the inside divs will return that div and not `div#foo`. Any idea how to always target `div#foo` when clicking on one of the element inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `currentTarget`  instead of `target`

```
<div id="foo" (click)="$event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('selected')">
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
   <div>...</div>
</div>
```